# menu is broken now for me

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, menu, bug-reporting

After the last update my unity menu works incorrectly.
If I click on any shortcut icon when window of program is below this menu. Click seems to work on window. Not on Launcher menu with shortcuts. You can see menu, but click window below....

PS: Menu works properly when desktop below.

Comment: Does the Unity menu work correctly after you run this command from the terminal: `setsid compiz --replace && setsid unity` ? Even if it only works temporarily, it would help to know about it so that the Unity menu problem could be fixed permanently.

Comment: @karel Yes. It's fixed now.  And it works after restart. Thank you. Can  I get an answer what cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you booted the computer the Unity desktop environment did not load correctly, so the Launcher isn't working properly. To fix this problem restart Unity. Open the terminal and type:

```
setsid compiz --replace && setsid unity
```

I have seen this problem occur on an older version of Ubuntu. The problem disappeared by itself after doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. After installing Ubuntu 14.04, I sometimes got an error message after updating the kernel, without any other problem occurring. This problem also disappeared after my Nvidia graphics card driver was updated by the Software Updater.

Comment: PS: It worked properly since boot till update from Update Center has asked about reboot.

Comment: If you don't reboot Ubuntu manually, the software updates will be enabled the next time you start the computer and boot Ubuntu.